# Data fetching with nextjs 'catch all' routes

Tags: reactjs, next.js, getstaticprops

With nextjs 10, you can have a catch all route, which looks something like this `[...id].tsx`. The idea is that this will allow for dynamic pages. So it should match `/example`, `/example/new`, `/example/new/latest` etc.

The issue im facing is that a specific matched routes (for example `/example/new`) may need extra data in order to correctly render. Seeing as i only really have one file in my `pages` folder, i only have access to one `getStaticProps` call. Fetching all possible data for all possible routes seems quite wasteful.

Server side data fetching at the component level would solve his issue but this doesn't seem to be a supported feature in nextjs

Is there a recommended way around this? Conditional data fetching based on context inside `getStaticProps` ?

Answer (score 0):

Where you should fetch data depends on the nature of your data. Also, when a user needs the data. You can use `getStaticProps`, `getServerSideProps` or fetch data on the client-side. See [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) to learn differences between the methods.